# Converting latin1 to UFT8 in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Please help me to change the encoding to UTF8? Encoding is in latin1 the fields are in latin format.

I need to change in MongoDB database.

How to change the encoding of a database from latin 1 to utf 8.

```
db.collection.insert(array("title" = utf8_encode("Péter")));
```

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB supports UTF-8 out of the box. So the encoding should not be in the MongoDB but in the data you insert.

The String as no Encoding so changing the encoding can be performed by changing to byte array and enforce the UTF-8 encoding.

If you are using JAVA 7 try this:

```
byte titleValue[] = myString.getBytes(ISO_8859_1); 
String value = new String(titleValue, UTF_8);
```